# How to add "last edited" date except on specific sheet

Tags: google-sheets

Im using the following code to update cell A2 with a last edited date:

```
function onEdit(e) {
   if (!e.value) return;
   e.source.getActiveSheet()
       .getRange('A2')
       .setValue(new Date());
}
```

Now i want this NOT to happen when a specific Sheet is active, named "Namen":

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var currentSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName();
   if (currentSheet != 'Namen' && !e.value) return;
   e.source.getActiveSheet()
       .getRange('A2')
       .setValue(new Date());
}
```

But the last edited date is still written to cell A2 when sheet 'Namen' is active.  What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to do a conditional check such as

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var currentSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if (currentSheet.getName() == "Namen"){
     return
  } else {
     e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange('A2').setValue(new Date());
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! I believe there was a typo in your code, but i got the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this code to get it to work:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName() == "Namen"){ 
    return
  }
  else
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange('A2').setValue(new Date());
}
```